# Trying to populate a form with JSON data, everything comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, umbraco

I am using Umbraco CMS, which is an ASP.NET website built on .NET Framework. I have an API that returns JSON data. My ultimate goal is to display this data in a form that can then be modified and sent to a different API to update the data.

However, the problem is that I just see undefined on data[i].anything. It also loops forever until I close my browser.

This is the controller method that gets the data from the external API:

```
[HttpGet()]
    public string GetReportParamaters(string id)
    {
        string json;
        
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
            json = wc.DownloadString("http://apiurl/" + id);

        }

        return json;
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint here, it appears to be working. When I visit the URL that corresponds to this method, the JSON is wrapped in an XML tag, I am not sure if that is part of the problem. But either way I see the data I expect in JSON.

This is the HTML and Javascript on my view to display the JSON data, this is where I am seeing undefined:

HTML:

```
<form id="ssrsData">

</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$("#reports").change(function () {
    $.get("/ControllerURL", { id: $('#reports').find(":selected").val() }, function (data) {
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            s += '<label for="' + data[i].Name + '">' + data[i].Name + ':</label><input type="text" id="' + data[i].Name + '" name="' + data[i].Name + '" value="' + data[i].Value + '"><br><br>'

        }
        $("#ssrsData").html(s);
    });
});
```

The JavaScript looks for a dropdown to be changed. When an option is selected, it sends the ID to the controller to get the JSON data. It then parses the JSON in HTML and added text boxes for each JSON object.

At least in theory, both data[i].Name and data[i].Value show undefined. The loop is also infinte, it just keeps adding text boxes until I stop it.

When I call $.get("/controllerURL") in Chrome's console it looks like it is returning my JSON data.

What do I need to do so that I can generate the form with my JSON data?

Comment: If anyone stumbles on this in the future, the solution was to change the return type of my controller to HttpResponseMessage and remove the headers.